# Copy only a part of the contents of file1.txt to file2.txt

Tags: c, file

I have to create a program that copies the contents of `file1.txt` to `file2.txt`, but it will not just "copy paste" all the contents of `file1.txt` to `file2.txt`

For example, `file1.txt` contains:

```
Name: Katrina , Age: 19 , Hobbies: Coding
Name: Karl, Age: 21, Hobbies: Guitar
```

`file2.txt` will copy the content of `file1.txt` but only until Age. So `file2.txt` will contain:

```
Name: Katrina, Age: 19
Name: Karl, Age: 21
```

---

At first, my thought process was:

1. Put `", Hobbies"` into a string
2. Count the number of characters in `file1.txt` until it reads `", Hobbies"` (counter)
3. Counter will copy the file1.txt character per character, count times.

---

This is my code:

```
FILE *ptr1;
FILE *ptr2;
        char c[100];
        int count = 1;
        char end[100];
        char k;

        strcpy(end, ", Hobbies");

        ptr1= fopen("file1.txt", "r");
        ptr2 = fopen("file2.txt", "a");


        while((k = fgetc(ptr1) != end)
        {
            if (k == ' ')
                count++;
        }
```

Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Your `while` loop's guard is comparing a single character to a string; that's not how to test for having read `", Hobbies"`.

Comment: Is the logic I'm using correct though? And how can I correct it?

Comment: Read lines ([`fgetc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html) or POSIX
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) and then find the start of `, Hobbies` as a string ([`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html)), and replace it with newline and null before printing.  Or find `Age: ` and a couple of digits, and then replace what follows with newline and null.  That more accurately reflects your "but only until Age" requirement, handling a record with other data before Hobbies.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are happy with the fact that the format of the file won't change, you can use a very simple method:

1 Read line.

2 Find ending string in line and cut it off.

3 Copy line to second file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char line[100];

FILE *ptr1 = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
FILE *ptr2 = fopen("file2.txt", "a");

// While no errors and no end of file when reading a line.
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), ptr1))
{
    // If you happen to have read empty lines from your file, re-read line.
    if (line[0] == '\n') continue;

    // Get position of end string.
    char *lineEnd = strstr(line, ", Hobbies");

    // Cut off the rest of the line with a null terminator.
    *lineEnd = '\0';

    // Write cut line into file2.txt.
    fprintf(ptr2, "%s\n", line);
}

// Close files.
fclose(ptr1);
fclose(ptr2);

return 0;
}
```

Or if you know you won't have empty lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char line[100];
    FILE *ptr1 = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
    FILE *ptr2 = fopen("file2.txt", "a");

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), ptr1))
    {
        char *lineEnd = strstr(line, ", Hobbies");
        *lineEnd = '\0';
        fprintf(ptr2, "%s\n", line);
    }

    fclose(ptr1);
    fclose(ptr2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do like the use of strstr in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

strtok breaks a string into series of tokens using delimiter. Here you can use "," as your delimiter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        FILE *fp1;
        FILE *fp2;

        char line[100];
        char *token;
        const char s[2] = ",";

        fp1 = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
        fp2 = fopen("file2.txt", "a");

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp1))
        {
                token = strtok(line,s);
                fprintf(fp2,"%s",token);
                token = strtok(NULL, s);
                fprintf(fp2,"%s\n",token);
        }
        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok` to find the delimiter. Read it's man page and then you should be able to figure out the rest yourself.

One hint: For each line you read, you will call `strtok` exactly once.

Comment: I'm currently reading through it, and I'm afraid I don't understand how to use it for this program :/ I have to define the string (which would be the first few chracters of one line in my file), then I will declare the limiter(?) to be ", Hobbies". Then, I will print the first token. Is this correct? But how can I save the first few lines of my file into a string? Thank you

Comment: printing the token would be `printf("%s", ...);` or something like that. Then, writing to the file would just be `fprintf(ptr2, "%s", ...);`.

Comment: And, BTW, actually, you understood it very well ;)

Comment: Oh, wait, you're supposed to call `strtok` on the lines individually, not on the entire file.

Comment: Thank you! So I read it per line, but how do I save the first few lines of file1.txt (Name: Katrina, Age: 19) into a string? :o And if i do it per line, this means I will use a loop til I reach EOF?

Comment: You loop until eof and you write to the file using `fprintf(ptr2` - see my other comment above. /edit: one line at a time

Comment: _One hint: For each line you read, you will call strtok exactly once._  Not true.  Each delimited segment in the line needs to be tokenized.  First call, `strtok()` is called with string to be parsed in the first argument.  After first call, `strtok()` is called with `nul` as the first argument for as many times as there is a new token.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a single bash command, but if you must have a c program, one solution is to copy one line at a time into the buffer, then search the buffer for occurrences of your delimiter. At the desired number of occurrences, replace the delimiter with a null character. When you write the string to the second file, it will stop at the null character. Then add a newline character. Like so:

```
FILE *ptr1;
FILE *ptr2;
char c[100];
char delim = ',';

ptr1 = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
ptr2 = fopen("file2.txt", "a");

while(fgets(c, 100, ptr1))
  {
    int i = 0;
    //find first delimiter
    while (c[i] != delim && c[i] != '\0') i++;
    //only advance index if we are not at the end of the string
    if(c[i] != '\0') i++;
    //find second delimeter
    while (c[i] != delim && c[i] != '\0') i++;
    //replace delimeter with null byte
    c[i] = '\0';
    //write out to second file
    fputs(c, ptr2);
    //fgets will contain newline at end of string,
    //  so only print newline to file if we did not print the whole string 
    if (c[i-1] != '\n') fputc('\n', ptr2);
  }
```

Also your code above is not complete - you have no include files and no main function. Also, don't forget to close the file pointers after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is good at this. Here is the command for what you need:

```
awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$2}' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: op is asking for a solution in c. it seems you proposed a smart solution but it doesn't match op's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using the strtok as originally suggested by @Bodo Thiesen.  This version does add a bit more checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define INPUT_FILE_NAME   "input.txt"
#define OUTPUT_FILE_NAME  "output.txt"
#define TOKEN_STR         ","


int main(void)
{
    FILE    *inputFile,
            *outputFile;
    char    *curLine = NULL,
            *token;
    size_t  len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    inputFile = fopen(INPUT_FILE_NAME, "r");
    if (NULL == inputFile) {
        printf("Could not open the input file '%s'\n", INPUT_FILE_NAME);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    outputFile = fopen(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "w");
    if (NULL == outputFile) {
        printf("Could not open the output file '%s'\n", OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
        fclose(inputFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((read = getline(&curLine, &len, inputFile)) != -1) {
        printf("%s\n", curLine);
        token = strtok(curLine, TOKEN_STR);
        fprintf(outputFile, "%s", token);
        fprintf(outputFile, ", ");
        token = strtok(NULL, TOKEN_STR);
        fprintf(outputFile, "%s\n", token);
    }

    fclose(outputFile);
    fclose(inputFile);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```